# Adding custom metadata tags to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, mp4, exiftool

I have modified the sound track of a 360 video using openshot.
The output has lost the 360 metadata tags. I am trying to use ffmpeg to replace them with the following command

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -movflags use_metadata_tags 
-metadata Spherical=true 
-metadata Stitched=true
-metadata "Projection Type"=equirectangular 
-codec copy 
output.mp4
```

Spherical and Stitched appear in the ouput file (viewed using exiftool) but the "Projection Type" doesn't. If I remove the quotes it generates an error. How do I put a custom metadata tag in with a space?

Answer (score 1):

Exiftool apparently doesn't like tags keys with spaces. In order to display in that app, Projection Type has to be ProjectionType.

It shows up either way in ffmpeg.

Comment: On most Unix shells (sh/bash/zsh), these are completely identical.

Comment: Yes, but ffmpeg.exe indicates Windows.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, same result as before

Comment: What didn't work?

Comment: -metadata "Projection Type=equirectangular"

Comment: Did you read my whole answer?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that is confusing. So you are saying that even though I can't see it through exiftool, it is actually there?

Comment: Yes, check with `ffmpeg -i output`

Comment: You can see the "Projection Type" data in the file with exiftool if you add the [-u (unknown)](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#u--unknown) option, though it won't have a tag name.  In my test, exiftool showed it as `Unknown_0x0005                  : equirectangular`

Comment: Followup: I brought this up on the exiftool forum and this will be supported in the next version.

Comment: Without the space, the tag does show up in Exiftool with the tag name. Is ProjectionType a recognized tag?

Comment: `ProjectionType` is recognized by exiftool as a [Matroska Projection Tag](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Matroska.html#Projection) or a [XMP GPano Tag](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/XMP.html#GPano) but neither of those seem to be the correct tag in this case.  I would assume that exiftool is taking the name from the file.  The OP mentions it is custom metadata.  [Here](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,10137.msg52785.html#msg52785) is Phil's post on the subject.

Comment: The ability to read tags with a space in the name in mp4 files has been fixed as of [version 11.44](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/history.html#v11.44).